# How to make it such that order doesnt matter in xsd with maxOccurrence > 1

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following xml, which I'd like to accept:

```
<Movies>
    <Title>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>500219855</PlatformID>
        <Type>Movie</Type>
    </Title>
    <Title>
        <Type>Movie</Type>
        <Platform>Hulu</Platform>
        <PlatformID>50019855</PlatformID>
        <Platform>ITunes</Platform>
    </Title>
</Movies>
```

I am currently using an `xs:sequence`, but that restricts ordering. I also tried using an `xs:all` instead, but that only allows a `maxOccurrence` of 0 or 1, so wouldn't work in the above case where I have 2 Platform values. How would I accomlish the above with an xsd sceme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried using `<xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:choice>`

The key is to combine xs:choice with maxOccurs="unbounded". If you just use xs:all, you are allowed one of each, period.

While xs:any will work, it won't limit your choices to the four elements itemized. It will allow anything, which pretty much defeats the purpose of a schema.